# Lost my unused Uk visit visa

Tags: visas, uk, lost-documents

I lost my passport with UK Visit Visa which I hadn’t used as yet. Do I need to reapply for a fresh visit visa, or can it be transferred?

Answer (score 1):

This can be transferred using details here:

> ### 2. ECB17.2 Replacing a visa (or leave) where this has been lost or stolen (excluding 30 day short validity (travel) vignettes)
>
> If the applicant loses their passport and visa, or has their passport and visa stolen, they are applying for a replacement using transfer of conditions. There will be a vignette transfer fee for the service.
>
> ...
>
> Any visa holder seeking to transfer an existing visa to a new passport is not making a fresh application for entry clearance and so cannot be compelled to provide biometrics as part of the transfer process, regardless of whether their initial application was accompanied by biometric enrolment. As part of the transfer process, ECOs should request that the applicant provides their biometric data, but should not automatically refuse the application if the applicant does not wish to do so.
>
> If applicants do not provide their biometrics, they must be advised that we will need to undertake further enquiries to establish their identity which may delay their application. If the ECO is not satisfied that the applicant is the person who is entitled to the new document, the application must be refused.

([Source](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/transferring-a-visa-to-a-new-passport-ecb17/transferring-a-visa-ecb17))